# Filter YouTube Videos which can not be played on iphone device (yt:accessControl embed and syndicate) fields

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api

I am using this api to fetch youtube videos

API that i am hitting is:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/movies/trending?v=2&paid-content=false&hl=en&alt=json&format=5

Can you please suggest some way so that i can send some parameters in this api that can filter the results on basis of yt:accsessControl embed and syndicate fields... so how to embed this fields in api to filter results

I have tried this :
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/movies/trending?v=2&paid-content=false&hl=en&alt=json&format=5&embed='allowed'&syndicate='allowed'

This does not filter the video results.. so please suggest what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

`format=5` effectively acts as a proxy to return only videos that are embeddable.

Similarly, you can use `format=1` (which is one of the public RTSP streams) to return only videos that have syndication enabled, since only those videos will have that format available.

You can't combine the two to get back only videos that have both set, though. If you say `format=1,5` you'll get back videos that have either set.

Comment: I am using this api:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/movies/trending?v=2&paid-content=false&hl=hi&region=IN&movie-genre=1&alt=json&format=5
 But as you can see its giving embed denied movies too :( what to do now